# Arrow function does not use local variable inside component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got a trouble with updating an object inside React component with events.

```
const Comp = (props) => {
  ...
  let tango = {alpha: null};
  ...
  let handleFirst = () => {
    tango.alpha = "CLICK";
    console.log(tango);
  }

  let handleSecond = () => {
    console.log(tango);
  }

  return (
    <div id="first" onClick={handleFirst}>text</div>
    <div id="second" onClick={handleSecond}>image</div>
  )
}
```

When I click on div `first` I receive the following console output: `{alpha: "CLICK"}`, but when I click on div `second` I receive console output as it is null: `{alpha: null}`. I don't want to include `tango` into `useState` function because I want to update state of the component after another trigger, so I don't need to render component after each edit of object.
It seems to me very discouragingly but I don't know what to I've tried almost everything, and it seems to me to add `alpha` to state will be solution but I hope I can avoid it.

Comment: *but when I click on div second I receive console output as it is null: `{alpha: null}`* No you won't It will log out `{alpha: "CLICK"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's some some re-rendering in between the first click on the second - if there wasn't, the `tango` closed over by the `handleFirst` that gets invoked would be the same one closed over by the invoked `handleSecond`:

```js
const Comp = (props) => {
  let tango = {alpha: null};
  let handleFirst = () => {
    tango.alpha = "CLICK";
    console.log(tango);
  }

  let handleSecond = () => {
    console.log(tango);
  }

  return (<div>
    <div id="first" onClick={handleFirst}>text</div>
    <div id="second" onClick={handleSecond}>image</div>
  </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Comp />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

If you want to keep a persistent reference to `tango` across re-renders, without the change to it causing a re-render itself, you can use a ref instead:

```js
const Comp = (props) => {
  let tangoRef = React.useRef({alpha: null});
  const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(0);
  let handleFirst = () => {
    tangoRef.current.alpha = "CLICK";
    setSomeState(someState + 1);
    console.log(tangoRef.current);
  }

  let handleSecond = () => {
    console.log(tangoRef.current);
  }

  return (<div>
    <div id="first" onClick={handleFirst}>text</div>
    <div id="second" onClick={handleSecond}>image</div>
  </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Comp />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually the problem was that there is a re-render of a minor component between clicks, so I haven't even mentioned it at my question.